# PyCharm : Administrative privileges required to install modules

Tags: python, tkinter, module, pycharm

I'm running pop-os and I just installed PyCharm, It can't seem to import tkinter so I tried installing it through PyCharm but it needs admin and you cant in linux.

Error :

```
Installing packages into 'Python 3.8' requires administrator privileges.

Configure a per-project virtual environment as your project interpreter
to avoid installing packages to a protected area of the file system.
```

I cant seem to find anything on google, I've tried every option on the error message but after I press anything the window closes.

---

**NeoFetch.**

---

```html
<pre><font color="#06989A"><b>             /////////////</b></font>                <font color="#06989A"><b>xiom</b></font>@<font color="#06989A"><b>pop-os</b></font> 
<font color="#06989A"><b>         /////////////////////</b></font>            ----------- 
<font color="#06989A"><b>      ///////</b></font><b>*767</b><font color="#06989A"><b>////////////////</b></font>         <font color="#06989A"><b>OS</b></font>: Pop!_OS 20.10 x86_64 
<font color="#06989A"><b>    //////</b></font><b>7676767676*</b><font color="#06989A"><b>//////////////</b></font>       <font color="#06989A"><b>Host</b></font>: HP Pavilion x360 Convertible 14 
<font color="#06989A"><b>   /////</b></font><b>76767</b><font color="#06989A"><b>//</b></font><b>7676767</b><font color="#06989A"><b>//////////////</b></font>      <font color="#06989A"><b>Kernel</b></font>: 5.11.0-7612-generic 
<font color="#06989A"><b>  /////</b></font><b>767676</b><font color="#06989A"><b>///</b></font><b>*76767</b><font color="#06989A"><b>///////////////</b></font>     <font color="#06989A"><b>Uptime</b></font>: 6 mins 
<font color="#06989A"><b> ///////</b></font><b>767676</b><font color="#06989A"><b>///</b></font><b>76767</b><font color="#06989A"><b>.///</b></font><b>7676*</b><font color="#06989A"><b>///////</b></font>    <font color="#06989A"><b>Packages</b></font>: 2158 (dpkg), 11 (flatpak),  
<font color="#06989A"><b>/////////</b></font><b>767676</b><font color="#06989A"><b>//</b></font><b>76767</b><font color="#06989A"><b>///</b></font><b>767676</b><font color="#06989A"><b>////////</b></font>   <font color="#06989A"><b>Shell</b></font>: bash 5.0.17 
<font color="#06989A"><b>//////////</b></font><b>76767676767</b><font color="#06989A"><b>////</b></font><b>76767</b><font color="#06989A"><b>/////////</b></font>   <font color="#06989A"><b>Resolution</b></font>: 1920x1080 
<font color="#06989A"><b>///////////</b></font><b>76767676</b><font color="#06989A"><b>//////</b></font><b>7676</b><font color="#06989A"><b>//////////</b></font>   <font color="#06989A"><b>DE</b></font>: GNOME 3.38.3 
<font color="#06989A"><b>////////////,</b></font><b>7676</b><font color="#06989A"><b>,///////</b></font><b>767</b><font color="#06989A"><b>///////////</b></font>   <font color="#06989A"><b>WM</b></font>: Mutter 
<font color="#06989A"><b>/////////////*</b></font><b>7676</b><font color="#06989A"><b>///////</b></font><b>76</b><font color="#06989A"><b>////////////</b></font>   <font color="#06989A"><b>WM Theme</b></font>: Pop 
<font color="#06989A"><b>///////////////</b></font><b>7676</b><font color="#06989A"><b>////////////////////</b></font>   <font color="#06989A"><b>Theme</b></font>: Pop-dark [GTK2/3] 
<font color="#06989A"><b> ///////////////</b></font><b>7676</b><font color="#06989A"><b>///</b></font><b>767</b><font color="#06989A"><b>////////////</b></font>    <font color="#06989A"><b>Icons</b></font>: Pop [GTK2/3] 
<font color="#06989A"><b>  //////////////////////</b></font><b>&apos;</b><font color="#06989A"><b>////////////</b></font>     <font color="#06989A"><b>Terminal</b></font>: gnome-terminal 
<font color="#06989A"><b>   //////</b></font><b>.7676767676767676767,</b><font color="#06989A"><b>//////</b></font>      <font color="#06989A"><b>CPU</b></font>: Intel i5-1035G1 (8) @ 3.600GHz 
<font color="#06989A"><b>    /////</b></font><b>767676767676767676767</b><font color="#06989A"><b>/////</b></font>       <font color="#06989A"><b>GPU</b></font>: Intel Iris Plus Graphics G1 
<font color="#06989A"><b>      ///////////////////////////</b></font>         <font color="#06989A"><b>Memory</b></font>: 4548MiB / 7640MiB 
<font color="#06989A"><b>         /////////////////////</b></font>
<font color="#06989A"><b>             /////////////</b></font>                <span style="background-color:#333333"><font color="#333333">   </font></span><span style="background-color:#CC0000"><font color="#CC0000">   </font></span><span style="background-color:#4E9A06"><font color="#4E9A06">   </font></span><span style="background-color:#C4A000"><font color="#C4A000">   </font></span><span style="background-color:#3465A4"><font color="#3465A4">   </font></span><span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#75507B">   </font></span><span style="background-color:#06989A"><font color="#06989A">   </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#D3D7CF">   </font></span>
                                          <span style="background-color:#88807C"><font color="#88807C">   </font></span><span style="background-color:#F15D22"><font color="#F15D22">   </font></span><span style="background-color:#73C48F"><font color="#73C48F">   </font></span><span style="background-color:#FFCE51"><font color="#FFCE51">   </font></span><span style="background-color:#48B9C7"><font color="#48B9C7">   </font></span><span style="background-color:#AD7FA8"><font color="#AD7FA8">   </font></span><span style="background-color:#34E2E2"><font color="#34E2E2">   </font></span><span style="background-color:#EEEEEC"><font color="#EEEEEC">   </font></span>
</pre>
```

---

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Do this in your console)

For tkinter:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

For other modules:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip

sudo pip install yourpackagename
```

To import the module you installed you write `import yourpackagename` in your Python file

Comment: How do I pip install tkinter?
pip install python3-tkinter doesnt work.

Comment: How do I install it?

Comment: I think `pip install yourpackagename` will fail with same privilege error.  Either use `pip install --user yourpackagename` or `sudo pip install yourpackagename`.

Comment: @Banned You cannot install `tkinter` using `pip`.  Try `sudo apt install python3-tk` in console instead.

Comment: @acw1668 isn't tkinter bundled with python?

Comment: No in some Linux distros.